# Passing credentials with Sharepoint

Tags: iis, sharepoint, sql

I have a sharepoint server and SQL server installed on different machines.

I created a web service which makes connection to the SQL serevr and gets data. If I test the web service it works.

Now when I create a web part in sharepoint and then use that web service to get data then it says `error occured accessing a data source`. When I make the web application anonymous then it gets the data from sql server.

I am deploying the web service in sharepoint layouts folder and I have code which runs with the web application `app pool` account. I want this `app pool` account to be passed to sql server, but it does not seem to pass the credentials.

Can someone please guide me on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is Kerberos, make sure you have properly configured it. Take a look at [this post](http://www.harbar.net/presentations/kerberos.pdf), and also check the entire blog of [Spence Harbars](http://www.harbar.net).